# header file and register configuration settinggs for MSD usb implementation using pic18f4550

Tags: microcontroller, usb, microchip

I want to implement USB mass storage device class as well as the human interface device class, the controller I am using is the PIC18F4550.

since I am very new to microcontroller, can anyone please guide me for this?

Here are some of the details of my task, I have used the given code, modified it a bit and had run the simulation, I could just detect my usb device attached with controller.
I am using Proteus 8.0 and MicroC 6.0 for simulation purpose.

I haven't included any header(.h) file yet, I have knowledge of including USBdsc.c i.e. the descriptors file, I don't know yet, which else to include.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned char readbuff[64] absolute 0x500;   // Buffers should be in USB RAM, please consult datasheet
unsigned char writebuff[64] absolute 0x540;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void interrupt()
{
   USB_Interrupt_Proc();                   // USB servicing is done inside the interrupt
}


void lcd(char d[64])
{
 char l[63];
 int a=0;
 for(a=0;a<63;a++)
 {
  l[a]=d[a+1];
 }
 lcd_cmd(_lcd_clear);
 lcd_out_cp(l);
}
//////////-------------------------------------------------------------------
int strToInt(char *string)
{
 int output = 0, i = 1, stringLength = strlen(string), temp = 0, numberLength = 0,j;
 char tempCh;

 for(j=0;j<stringLength;j++)
 {
  tempCh = string[j];
  temp = tempCh - 48;
  if (temp >= 0 && temp <= 9)
  {
   numberLength++;
  }
 }

 for(j=0;j<stringLength;j++)
 {
  tempCh = string[j];
  temp = tempCh - 48;
  if (temp >= 0 && temp <= 9)
  {
   output += temp * pow(10, (numberLength-i));
   i++;
  }
 }

 return output;
}
 // pwm function////---------------------
void pwm(char d[64])
{
 char l[3];
 int a=0;
 for(a=0;a<3;a++)
 {
  l[a]=d[a+1];
  }
 for(a=0;a<5;a++)
 {
  portc=~portc;
  vdelay_ms(strtoint(l)*10);
 }
  //pwm1_set_duty(l);
//  pwm1_start();
}
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


void main(void)
{
 int a;
 //-----------------------------------------------variable area--------------------------------------
 trisb=0; // port as output
 portb=0xff;
 trisc=0;
 portc=0xff;
 ADCON1 |= 0x0F;                         // Configure all ports with analog function as digital
 CMCON  |= 7;
 lcd_init();
 lcd_cmd(_lcd_cursor_off);
HID_Enable(readbuff,writebuff);      // Enable HID communication
pwm1_init(5000);// start pwn module and  set on 5 KHz

while(1)
 {
  if(!(hid_read()==0))
  {
    /*usb_read_filter(readbuff);*/
    /*lcd_cmd(_lcd_clear);
    lcd_out_cp(readbuff);*/
    if(readbuff[0]=='0')
    {
     lcd(readbuff);
    }
    else if(readbuff[0]=='1')
    {
         pwm(readbuff);
    }

    while(!hid_write(readbuff,64));
  }// if Data read  endz

 }  // while endz
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Microchip has available their [Microchip Libraries for Applications (MLA)](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/devtools/mla/), which includes sample code for the PIC16, PIC18, PIC24 and dsPIC33 (the MLA used to also include the PIC32, but that now has a different library called MPLAB Harmony).  The MLA library includes code for graphics, crypto, file I/O and USB.

I have an older version on my desktop, but looking through the directories I see that it includes several versions of USB HID: custom, digitizer, joystick, keyboard, mouse, and UPS. There is code for, among others, the PIC18F46J50, PIC18F47J53 and PIC18F87J50.  If the latest version doesn't include the PIC18F4550 you can probably adapt one of the others.  For the custom HID application, the library also includes Visual C++ code (2005 Express edition) for the Windows side.

So you will get a lot more than just the header files etc, you will have source code for complete, running applications that you can adapt for your own use.

The MLA also includes mass storage device code for internal flash, SD card data logger, and SD card reader applications.  Code for the same three PIC18s is included.

I have an Explorer 16 board along with the USB and SD card accessories, and the PIC24/PIC32 versions of the mass storage firmware compiled and ran "right out of the box" without any modifications.  I was then able to merge their code into the code already running on my custom PCB with very little effort.

Comment: u can see the small code now, I am really very sorry, I don't know how to add the code here, it got merged up..

Comment: @student8661 Before trying to merge Microchip's code with you own, you should try to get their code working by itself first, preferably on your own hardware but if not, at least in the simulator.

Comment: Okay I try it again